# Module design to micro-services in Node.js; would like to weigh some choices and get more specific examples

Tags: node.js, export-to-csv, watson-conversation

Our platform:  IBM Bluemix platform, IBM Watson Conversation, SLACK client.  Code is deployed in Node.js runtime.

We have a simple bot that mediates a conversation between SLACK user and IBM Watson service.   The conversation allows the user to specify query components to get Billing data or Cost data from back end services.   Works well, for small data sets....

We want our bot to handle larger data sets that come from the back end service.  The use case we are pursuing in this:
SLACK User interacts with the Watson conversation, provides necessary query input, query runs, query results are turned into a CSV file (spreadsheet) and parked in BOX content manager which we have available.  Once the job finishes, the user receives notification in SLACK that the data is in the Box file, with the link provided.

Being a novice Node.js programmer I don't have a good grasp on how to structure the components to handle this type of asynchronous exchange.  My hunch tells me that I should create functions to handle the discrete tasks:  1) calling remote service and bringing data back, 2) wrapping data into CSV format, 3) creating file in BOX, returning link, 4) notifying SLACK user with message including link to the data file in Box.

My research tells me that I should be using Node's Promises, but not sure exactly how to break things down or how to 'Promisify' things so they work together as planned.  Is this what I should be pursuing?  If so, a nice easy example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to follow these steps, you can use [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) or, [Promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise), see one example:

```
function csvFunc(params) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //do something CSV
    });
}

function boxManager(params) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //do something box, create box
    });
}

Promise.all([csvFunc(params), boxManager(params)]) //add the functions what you want,
    .then(function(allData) { //after all functions are Ok, then....
        // return the value for slack or what you want to do
        console.log("All functions have perfomed")
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Sayuri-san;
I did some studying on the technique you recommended.   I believe that the Promise.all([list])...  will execute all of the functions in Parallel.  What I need to do is to execute each asynch call sequentially, passing the results of each call to the next successive function:
getData() > transformDataToCSV() > recordDataInBOX > return with link
Notify SLAcK client with link to data

I believe I need to do something like this:
getData()
  .then(transformDataToCSV())
  .then(recordDataInBOX())
  .then(notifySLACKClient())

Comment: So, use async for that, but promise can be used like your example